# Custom confirm dialog not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I want to use custom CSS for my confirm messages.

I've used this tutorial to get going:
http://thelazylog.com/custom-dialog-for-data-confirm-in-rails/

My JS:

```
//Override the default confirm dialog by rails
$.rails.allowAction = function(link){
  if (link.data("confirm") == undefined){
    return true;
  }
  $.rails.showConfirmationDialog(link);
  return false;
}

//User click confirm button
$.rails.confirmed = function(link){
  link.data("confirm", null);
  link.trigger("click.rails");
}

//Display the confirmation dialog
$.rails.showConfirmationDialog = function(link){
  var message = link.data("message");
  var title = link.data("title");
  $.fn.SimpleModal({
    model: "modal",
    title: title,
    contents: message
  }).addButton("Confirm", "button alert", function(){
    $.rails.confirmed(link);
    this.hideModal();
  }).addButton("Cancel", "button secondary").showModal();
}
```

On my view page I have following link:

```
<%= link_to "next page", nextpage_path, data: {confirm: "", message: "We need your confirmation", title: "Please confirm"} %>
```

Once I click this link it displays the modal correctly, but once I click on confirm, it just closes the modal, and I have to reclick the link in order for me to be redirected to the next page.

Current behaviour in gif:
[image]

So in short, the $.rails.confirmed(link); and this.hideModal(); are working, but I need it to redirect to the path specified in the link_to.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: In the normal circumstance, it should trigger the default action of the link after you click Confirm. Do you see any errors in the Developer console?

Comment: No errors are shown and it is a default link_to with data confirm so I don't see what the issue could be

Comment: Can you put a log inside `$.rails.confirmed` function to make sure it really goes there? I do not see any problem with the code actually, something other things must be wrong.